# Extract and unzip an email attachment

Tags: python, email-attachments, unzip

I have a piece of Python code that trawls my email inbox for a specific daily email based on the sender and the subject line and then downloads the attachment to a local drive for later use.  The attachment was a csv file and the code worked fine.  Now the sender has changed the attachment to be a zipped file.

How do I amend my code to be able to download the zip and extract the csv file?

I have tried some of the solutions provided on this site but I cannot get the them to work so I thought it might be worth seeing if anyone had any way to amend the code I already have.
[extract attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOIbg.png)

Comment: use [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

Comment: and please no code in images. just plain text in your question

Comment: After your code saves the attachment, you can use the zipfile module to extract the contents of the zip file into a folder that you provide, and read the csv file that you expect. Refer this [article](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-unzip-a-file-extract-single-multiple-or-all-files-from-a-zip-archive/)  for various ways of extracting zip file contents.